# Matlab subsref and end

Tags: matlab, operator-overloading

I have a custom matrix class, that I want to be able to index as:

```
x = myobj(1,2).d(3,4)     % myobj(1,2,3,4)
x = myobj(2, 3).d(3, end) % myobj(1,3,1,end)
```

I want these to work for assignment too.

I've started with:

```
class MyClass < double
  methods
    function obj = MyClass(x)
      obj = obj@double(x);
    end
    function obj = subsref(obj, s)
      varargout{:} = subsref@double(obj, subsintercept(obj, s));
    end
    function obj = subsasgn(obj, s, b)
      obj = subsasgn@double(obj, subsintercept(obj, s), b);
    end
  end
end
```

And then I can mess with the indexing in `subsintercept`. However, I've hit a problem. With a minimal implementation:

```
function s = subsintercept(obj, s)
    disp('subsintercept');
    for i = 1:length(s)
        disp(s(i));
    end
end
```

I get this expected behaviour

```
>> myobj = MyClass(zeros(1,2,3,4))
>> myobj(1,2).d(3,4)
subsintercept
type: '()'
subs: {[1]  [2]}
type: '.'
subs: 'd'
type: '()'
subs: {[3]  [4]}
<error due to not having finished subsintercept yet>
```

But this unexpected

```
>> myobj(1,2).d(3,end)
subsintercept
type: '()'
subs: {[1]  [2]}
type: '.'
subs: 'd'
<error due to not having finished subsintercept yet>
```

1. Why does adding the `end` cause me not to receive the `3`?
2. Is this behaviour documented?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on what you class looks like. Is `d` a dynamic property or what?

Comment: @Suever: `d` doesn't exist. The class is a subclass of `double`. There are no properties or other methods, other than an uninteresting constructor. I've added the boilerplate for all this now, but I think it occludes clarity somewhat

Comment: Since `d` doesn't exist, MATLAB has no way of converting `end` to anything useful. What do you expect `end` to yield?

Comment: @Suever: I was hoping that I would get passed an `end` object of some kind

Answer (score 0):

Some testing reveals that this:

```
result = myobj(1,2).d(3,end)
```

Is translated to:

```
end_ = str2func('end');
d_temp = subsref(myobj, substruct('()', {1 2}, '.', 'd'));
ei = end_(d_temp, 2, 2);
result = subsref(myobj, substruct('()', {1 2}, '.', 'd', '()', {3, ei}));
```

i.e., that `subsref` gets called twice!<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*And surprisingly, not as `subsref(d_temp, substruct('()', {3, ei}))`the second time</sup>

Comment: I guess this makes sense as `myobj(1,2).d` needs to be resolved before it's possible to even determine what to do with an `end`. It may be worth fleshing this out a bit to make it a bit clearer how you can write your `subsref` to cope with this.

Comment: @suever: I will when I get around to implementing it. Seems that I need a proxy object of some kind in `d`